# Ros topics not listed for steered_wheel_base_controller plugin

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using the steered_wheel_base_controller plugin for my application. When I am loading it in a node, everything compiles and the node launches without any errors. But on listing the topic, the topics relevant to the plugin are not listed. Am I missing something?

The following is the `odom_publisher.cpp` file:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    
  ros::init (argc, argv, "odom_publisher");
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(1);
  spinner.start();
        
  pluginlib::ClassLoader<controller_interface::ControllerBase> odom_publisher("steered_wheel_base_controller","controller_interface::ControllerBase");
  try
  {

   boost::shared_ptr<controller_interface::ControllerBase> odom = odom_publisher.createInstance("steered_wheel_base_controller/SteeredWheelBaseController");
  }
  catch(pluginlib::PluginlibException& ex)
  {
    ROS_ERROR("The plugin failed to load for some reason. Error: %s", ex.what());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198939/ros-topics-not-listed-for-steered_wheel_base_controller-plugin/) by [Sphenop](https://answers.ros.org/users/21030/sphenop/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2014-12-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seeing as [steered_wheel_base_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/steered_wheel_base_controller) is a [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) plugin, I don't think you're supposed to load it like you do -- eg: directly using `pluginlib`.

You might want to take a look at the [ros_control/Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control/Tutorials) and the [presentation](http://roscon.ros.org/2014/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/ros_control_an_overview.pdf) of Adolfo at ROSCon14 last September on `ros_control`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0